# How to understand the pattern in conducting?

Tags: conducting

I know the conducting patterns but how do I decide which song needs which pattern?
I know it depends on beats and all, but I just can't get the sure shot method of finding the right pattern.
can the same song have different patterns?
for example one conductor uses the four pattern thrice while the other uses six pattern twice for the same tune.

Comment: What's this tune that some conduct in quadruple meter while others conduct in sextuple meter? There's such a thing as mixed meter (i.e. changing conducting patterns mid-piece), but I haven't heard of a tune that could be in either 4/4 or 6/8 time.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern is determined by the time signature. This is, for the most part, one pattern for each time signature. A song can move between time signatures so you may need more than one pattern per song but each conductor should use the same pattern as another conductor for the same song.

Answer (score 0):

Two different conductors, one using a pattern to indicate 4/4 time and the other using a pattern to indicate 6/8 time will be leading their musicians to play separate and distinct versions/arrangements of that same song. The conductors pattern is to indicate the rhythm of the music, and the rhythm may change inside the song, but this is led but the conductor and the musicians follow. Failure to adhere to this idea creates mayhem in the orchestra, as you can probably imagine.